How to show the orthogonality of associated Laguerre Polynomials in the Hydrogen Atom Radial Equation
In "Topics in Atomic Physics", Springer, by Charles E.Burkhardt and Jacob J. Leventhal, Chapter 4, Section 4.5.
To normalize the radial equation of hydrogen atom, it is necessary to use the orthogonality integral.
Using the Speigel's definitions of Laguerre polynomial and associated Laguerre polynomial:
$$L_n(x) = e^x\frac{d^n}{dx^n}[e^{-x}x^n]$$
$$L_n^m(x) = \frac{d^m}{dx^m}L_n(x)$$
Notice: this definition of $L_n(x)$ is without the $\frac{1}{n!}$ factor
The radial wave function $R_{nl}(r)$ is as followed, while $M_{nl}$ is the coefficient:
$$R_{nl}(r) = M_{nl}(\frac{2r}{na_0})^lexp(-\frac{r}{na_0})L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(\frac{2r}{na_0})$$
Question 1: how to show the orthogonality integral
$$\int_0^{\infty}x^pe^{-x}L_{q}^p(x)L_{q'}^p(x)dx = \frac{(q!)^3}{(q-p)!}\delta_{qq'}$$
Question 2: how to use the above result to show the integral
$$\int_0^{\infty}x^{2l}e^{-x}[L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(x)]^2x^2dx = \frac{2n[(n+l)!]^3}{(n-l-1)!}$$

After a few days of research, I am here to clarify and answer the question I asked.
First of all, these integrals are not for "Orthogonality of radial function". About the orthogonality of radial function, please refer to this post in SE Physics Proof of Orthogonality of Hydrogen Atom Wave Functions
These are for computing the integral value of the radial part of wave function of single-electron atoms. After obtaining the value we can decide the $M_{nl}$ coefficient.
The 2 integrals are listed in the bottom of this webpage, No.9, 10, and 13:
Laguerre Polynomials
The first one has an orthogonality and the second one doesn't. (I am studying on a textbook which says the second does, but it doesn't)
To culculate the second integral, it is nessasary to have the first orthogonality combining with a recurrence formula (No.5 in the page)of associated Laguerre Polynomials.
I'll list them here.
Orthogonality:
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^mL_n^m(x)L_{n'}^m(x)dx = \frac{(n!)^3}{(n-m)!}\delta_{nn'}$$
This can be proved by multiplication of generating function of associated Laguerre function.
Recurrence formula:
$$xL_n^m(x)=(2n+1-m)L_n^m(x)-n^2L_{n-1}^m(x)+\frac{m-n-1}{n+1}L_{n+1}^m(x)$$
This can be proved by differentiating the generating function of associated Laguerre function.
$$L_n(x) = e^x\frac{d^n}{dx^n}[e^{-x}x^n],\ L_n^m(x) = \frac{d^m}{dx^m}L_n(x)$$
Generating function of Laguerre function:
$$ \frac{1}{1-t}exp(\frac{-xt}{1-t}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}L_n(x)t^n$$
Generating function of associated Laguerre function:
$$ \frac{d^m}{dx^m}[\frac{1}{1-t}exp(\frac{-xt}{1-t})] = \frac{(-1)^mt^m}{(1-t)^{m+1}}exp(\frac{-xt}{1-t}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}L_n^m(x)t^n$$
Combining the orthogonality and recurrence formula above, we have:
$$ \begin{align} 
&   & \int_0^\infty & e^{-x}x^{m+1}L_n^m(x)L_n^m(x)dx \\ 
& = & \int_0^\infty & e^{-x}x^{m}L_n^m(x)(xL_n^m(x))dx \\ 
& = & \int_0^\infty & e^{-x}x^{m}L_n^m(x)[(2n+1-m)L_n^m(x)-n^2L_{n-1}^m(x)+\frac{m-n-1}{n+1}L_{n+1}^m(x)]dx \\ 
& = & \int_0^\infty & e^{-x}x^{m}L_n^m(x)[(2n+1-m)L_n^m(x)]dx\ (by\ Orthogonality) \\ 
& = &  (2n&+1-m)\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{m}L_n^m(x)L_n^m(x)dx \\ 
& = & (2n&+1-m)\frac{(n!)^3}{(n-m)!} 
\end{align} $$
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{2l+2}[L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(x)]^2dx = [2(n+l)+1-(2l+1)]\frac{[(n+l)!]^3}{[(n+l)-(2l+1)]!} = \frac{2n[(n+l)!]^3}{(n-l-1)!}$$
for $R_{nl}(r)$ integration:
$$R_{nl}(r) = M_{nl}(\frac{2r}{na_0})^lexp(-\frac{r}{na_0})L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(\frac{2r}{na_0})$$
$$\int_0^\infty[R_{nl}(r)]^2r^2dr = 1$$
$$\int_0^\infty(M_{nl})^2(\frac{2r}{na_0})^{2l}exp(-\frac{2r}{na_0})[L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(\frac{2r}{na_0})]^2 r^2dr = 1$$
let $x = \frac{2r}{na_0}$,
$$(M_{nl})^2(\frac{na_0}{2})^3\int_0^\infty x^{2l}e^{-x}[L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(x)]^2 x^2dx = 1$$
$$(M_{nl})^2(\frac{na_0}{2})^3\frac{2n[(n+l)!]^3}{(n-l-1)!} = 1$$
$$ M_{nl} = \pm[(\frac{2}{na_0})^3\frac{(n-l-1)!}{2n[(n+l)!]^3}]^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
Take the negative in $M_{nl}$ by convention in textbook.
$$R_{nl}(r) = -[(\frac{2}{na_0})^3\frac{(n-l-1)!}{2n[(n+l)!]^3}]^{\frac{1}{2}}(\frac{2r}{na_0})^lexp(-\frac{r}{na_0})L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(\frac{2r}{na_0})$$
$$n = 1, 2, 3,...;\ l = 0, 1, ..., n-1;\ a_0=\frac{\hbar^2}{\mu e^2}\ (Bohr\ radius)$$
By recurrence formula, it is clear that if $|n'-n|=1$ then the second integral is not $0$, thus there is no orthogonality in the second integral.
